# Getting started with EHCache

Tags: java, jar, ehcache

I am getting started with EHCache and downloaded the required .tar file from this location: [EHCache downloads](http://ehcache.org/downloads/catalog). I extracted the .tar file and added the below jars to my classpath.

1. ehcache-2.9.0
2. slf4j-api-1.7.7
3. slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7

I am not able to find CacheManager.java in any of the above mentioned jars. Is that located in some other .jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ehcache-2.9.0.jar does not contain the java source file. It does however contain the compiled class file for net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.

If you want the source file it can be found in the `src` directory of the unpacked distribution.

Comment: Yes you are correct sir. I thought I double checked that with the jar -tf command but I guess I missed it due to my shell height buffer not displaying all the compiled classes (facepalm). Thanks for confirming, I checked again and saw it is indeed there. I wasn't able to import into my eclipse project due to some classpath problem...